# Accessing remote database from Windows machine

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, powershell-v7

I tried to connect to a remote MySQL instance from my script in WSL2 but it always failed. I tested using the following command `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName my-db.com -Port 3306` from PowerShell v7 and got this result:

```
ComputerName           : my-db.com
RemoteAddress          : 123.123.123.123
RemotePort             : 3306
InterfaceAlias         : Wi-Fi
SourceAddress          : 192.192.192.192
PingSucceeded          : False
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

I've checked the firewall rules and I don't see any rule regarding port 3306. I've tried using VPN too to no avail. I'm really at my wit's end.

EDIT:
And yes, the remote server is open on that port because I can connect to it using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Most probably the database does not allow remote connections.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I can connect just fine using MySQL Workbench. @GeraldSchneider

Comment: Then compare the settings. You are not even providing enough information to guess.